# Shell/Bash Sort by file was last modified

Tags: bash, shell

How to please sort by file was last modified?

my tree

```
/home/abc1 (created 10.10.2001, 5:16:18 am)
/home/abc12 (created 8.1.2010, 2:12:11 pm)
/home/a/abc88 (created 1.11.2005, 4:16:20 pm) 
/home/a/b/c/abc74 (created 9.3.2006, 3:10:18 am)
```

I want to show on the screen (sort by file was last modified)

```
/home/abc1 10.10.2001 5:16:18 am
/home/a/abc88 1.11.2005 4:16:20 pm
/home/a/b/c/abc74 9.3.2006 3:10:18 am 
/home/abc12 8.1.2010, 2:12:11 pm
```

Please advise. Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with your list, once it is generated?

Answer (score 0):

From the [ls manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) you can use

```
ls -clt
```

this will show the last modified files first. Use `-cltr` to reverse the list

Comment: But it will list files and folder only in current directory not recursively.

Comment: But `ls -clrR` will group the files for each subdir and then sort. It will be sorted for each group but not overall.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
find <dir_name> -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' "{}" \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
find <Directory> -type f | xargs ls -ltr
```